# How to go from JOptionPane program to GUI interface

Tags: java

For a simple card game I am making, I would like to make a GUI in which I can play my card game. Previously, I was relying on JOptionPane's to show me what I drew. Now, I don't know how to draw a card with a GUI I made using the swing interface in NetBeans. So i'd like to know the best way to implement my original drawing method in a button with NetBeans generated GUI code. Thank you!

Here's the drawing Method:

```
public static void Draw() {

    System.out.println(player1 + " drew " + suits[cardSuit(deck1[deck1CardPosition])] + " of power " + (cardPower(deck1[deck1CardPosition])));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, player1 + " drew " + suits[cardSuit(deck1[deck1CardPosition])] + " of power " + (cardPower(deck1[deck1CardPosition])));

    System.out.println(player2 + " drew " + suits[cardSuit(deck2[deck2CardPosition])] + " of power " + (cardPower(deck2[deck2CardPosition])));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, player2 + " drew " + suits[cardSuit(deck2[deck2CardPosition])] + " of power " + (cardPower(deck2[deck2CardPosition])));

}
```

UPDATE: Adding the bloc of code NetBeans auto-generates for me:

```
private void DrawActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    }
```

The action listener:

```
Draw.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            DrawActionPerformed(evt);
        }
```

Comment: You place this same exact code into a ActionEvent on a button... Hard to help without seeing that other GUI code

Comment: I updated the post with the GUI code NetBeans generated for me

Comment: Okay, so do what it says... `TODO add your handling code here`

Comment: But I don't exactly know what to put there. I can't just copy paste my previous method because I don't want a window popping up showing my card. I want to know if I can call a method from another class by doing something like Draw drawCard = new Draw(); but that didn't work

Comment: `Draw` is not a class, is it? It's a static method. You cannot `new` a method. You can make a `Card` or `Deck` class yourself, then you would call `Card card = deck.draw()`, for example.

Comment: Try to focus on the actual classes of your application before working on any GUI functionality. Seems you still need to work on that

Answer (score 0):

You can use javax.swing and java.awt. libraries in order to implement what would you like to implement.

1. for the number of the card you drew, try putting its value in a jtextfield inside a JFrame
2. Design of the card can be implemented with the use of Graphics class.

Comment: Yes, i've done all that. My design is done, but now comes the functionality part and I don't know how to make my draw method work in the new GUI program

Comment: Would you mind sending a screenshot of the form and also the screenshot of the code? :)